# Why "SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT <Column>) FROM <Table>" return 0?

Tags: sql, database

I have run the query above for all columns in a massive table (Billion rows) and everything is fine except a couple which are returning 0. How is this possible?

Comment: Because all rows have a `NULL` value in that column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`COUNT(DISTINCT)` can return zero under two circumstances.  The first is that all the values for the column/expression evaluate to `NULL`.  The second is that the `WHERE` clause (or `JOIN`) filters out all rows.

If you have no `WHERE` or `JOIN`, then the values are all `NULL` for `<Columnb>`.

Comment: Oh yes that's it, they were all NULL. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To validate all the records in the column are having NULL values you can try the following query:

```
SELECT <columB> FROM <TABLE> WITH (NOLOCK) WHERE <columB> IS NOT NULL
```

it should return 0 Records.

Answer (score 0):

`count(column_name)` only counts rows where the column is NOT NULL.

So

```
select count(column_name)
from some_table;
```

is equivalent to

```
select count(*)
from some_table
where column_name is not null;
```

The distinct inside the `count()` is not relevant for this actually. But `count(distinct column_name)` is equivalent to:

```
select count(*)
from (
  select distinct column_name
  from some_table
  where column_name is not null
) t
```

Answer (score 0):

COUNT(*) on innodb sometimes returns 0.
Try to turn index_merge_intersection off:

```
SET SESSION optimizer_switch="index_merge_intersection=off";
```

Here is a Mysql 5.6 bugreport https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=81031

Answer (score -2):

run below query before your code:

```
<br>
$db->("SET NAMES UTF8");
```